# Increasing Size of VHD having DFSR Data

Tags: active-directory, windows-server-2012-r2, dfs-r, server-settings

I have two file servers which are replicating files through DFSR across two different locations over WAN link.  I want to increase one of partition size having replication group folders on it. I was just curious it will damage any thing related to db of replications on system and volume folder or any thing related to its content like staging or conflict / delete folders.

Q2. I need to delete one large folder from replicated folder what is best way to achieve it.

Thanks in advance.:)

Comment: Re:  folder deletion:  What Daniel said.  You could google "fastest folder deletion windows" (I have for a recurring deletion task, back when) but in the amount of time it takes to do that your folder would probably be deleted.

Answer (score 2):

You can safely extend the VHD. You need to extend the volume in the guest, too, afterwards.

Just delete the folder.